# Is CS0165 C# compiler error guaranteed for unassigned local variables?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, static-analysis

In code like this:

```
int val;

if (something())
   val = 10;

val++; // Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable
```

I get `CS0165` error message when a local variable is used when there's a chance it was not surely initialized before.

In C++ world this scenario is *undefined behavior* class situation, which means that anything is allowed. So maybe there's a compiler error, maybe there's a compiler warning, maybe there's a runtime error, maybe code just uses whatever was in memory at that moment and good luck noticing it.

Is `CS0165` guaranteed for such code in C#?

Is there a case where this specific piece of code does not yield an error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is CS0165 guaranteed for such code in C#?

Yes, the rules of definite assignment are designed so that a local variable can never be read before it's definitely been written.

It's pretty conservative, too - for example:

```
bool condition = false;
int x;
if (condition)
{
    x = 0;
}
if (!condition)
{
    x = 1;
}
Console.WriteLine(x); // Error
```

Here even though *we* know that exactly one of those `if` statement bodies will be entered, the compiler doesn't - so `x` isn't definitely assigned at the end.

The rules of definite assignment are in the C# 5 specification in section 5.3.

Note that various classes of variables (e.g. static fields, and instance fields of classes) are deemed "initially assigned" - but they have well-specified default values, so there's still no undefined behaviour there.

Comment: Using `else` instead of second `if` will make it possible for compiler to check what there is no undefined behavior.

Comment: @Sinatr Yes, this was deliberately designed as an example which the rules don't cover but human common sense does. But that's not to do with undefined behaviour - it's definite assignment.